# git clone giving errors

Tags: git, git-clone

error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200MiB | 243.00 KiB/s

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

fatal: early EOF

fatal: index-pack failed

I have made below git configurations but still not working..

```
[core] 
    packedGitLimit = 512m 
    packedGitWindowSize = 512m 
[http]
    postBuffer = 1048576000
    maxRequestBuffer = 100M
[push]
    default = current
[pack] 
    deltaCacheSize = 2047m 
    packSizeLimit = 2047m 
    windowMemory = 2047m
```

I am cloning git repo by

```
git clone http://pathtogit.git /var/www/html/myproject
```

**I have also tried git compression on/off** and also tried below command

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch developer http://path/path.git /var/www/html/project_folder
```

I am using **ubuntu 14.04** and **git version 1.9.1**

Comment: You tried increase the maxRequestBuffer param?

Comment: Did you try using Git 2.19? (with the right ppa: https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Answer (score 0):

This error message, `RPC failed; result=18`, means that the server reported a particular size for what you're downloading and the data was of a different size.  This often means that the remote repository has some sort of issue, or that you're using a broken proxy.

If you control the remote repository and it isn't managed explicitly by some software, you might run `git fsck` and `git repack -a -d` to see if that fixes the problem.

If not, you can try cloning via SSH and see if that fixes the problem; if so, then it may be due to a proxy (whether on your computer or elsewhere) that's intercepting things, or due to a network problem.